# Maximum POST Variables PHP?

Tags: php, html

I am submitting 5 stings to PHP from HTML 
I get an error on goDaddy (Internal Server error) when i try and pass 5 strings  **BUT  it works for 4 strings.** 
I cannot figure out the problem. Is there a maximum amount of POST variables that can be passed?
I works for 4 strings, and when i add another string i get an error.
Godaddy support team was useless was on the phone with them for Hours.
The coding works fine on WAMP!

## HTML

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">


  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
  <input type="text" name="clientID" id="client_id" value="" />
   <input type="text" name="redirect" id="redirect_uri" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="webstate" id="stateValue" value="" />







  <button>Login</button>
</form>
```

## PHP

```
$myusername=$_POST['username']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['password']; 
$client_id=$_POST['clientID']; 
$redirect_uri=$_POST['redirect'];
/*$state=$_POST['webstate']; */  <---- When i add this line it Shows 
                                       Internal Server Error 






echo "Username: ".$myusername. "<br />";
echo "Client ID: ".$client_id. "<br />";
echo "Redirect URL: ".$redirect_uri. "<br />";
/*echo "State: ".$state. "<br />"; */ <--- I commented this becouse it  
                                           useless
```

Comment: There is a limit, but by default it's 1,000 post vars... if you're getting an internal server error, check the logs to see what that error is

Comment: The logs are useless, they dont seems to show many errors. Just a bunch of logs of ip adresses and blah blah

Comment: What logs are you looking at, that sounds like it's just the webserver logs

Comment: check `error_log` file where the PHP is kept on the server and find out which line is creating the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very important to check if the posted values are set before assigning them to a variable or doing something with them.

`$myusername = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : "" ;`

`$mypassword= isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : "" ;`

`$client_id= isset($_POST['clientID']) ? $_POST['clientID'] : "" ;`

`$redirect_uri= isset($_POST['redirect']) ? $_POST['redirect'] : "" ;`

`$state= isset($_POST['webstate']) ? $_POST['webstate'] : "" ;`

Comment: Okay, now the error went away buy when i echo the $state variable it doesnt show anything. But in HTML text field i can cleary see the text

Comment: In that case the name of your input is probably not webstate. Can you try: `var_dump($_POST);`? What does it return?

Answer (score 0):

there is no maximum amount of POST request
Your code Is Ok, I tried it and it works perfectly
i just added one line to check the POST values

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

$myusername = $_POST['username']; 
$mypassword = $_POST['password']; 
$client_id = $_POST['clientID']; 
$redirect_uri = $_POST['redirect'];
$state = $_POST['webstate']; 

echo "Username: ".$myusername. "<br />";
echo "Client ID: ".$client_id. "<br />";
echo "Redirect URL: ".$redirect_uri. "<br />";
echo "State: ".$state. "<br />"; 
}
```

If the problem still appears try a different host

Comment: yahyazini's awnser woked but now the $state is empty. But in html text field for 'state' it it having a text

Comment: Meaning there is a text in the for the 'state' field in the HTML form, but when i get it to php its empty

Comment: i uploaded my code to free host and there is no problems check: https://admitted-curls.000webhostapp.com/stack.php